# I just can't add rows with the same name to another dataset?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

what i want to do; combining the data of columns of the same name in the dataset with the column of the same name in dataset2.However, when I select join = 'inner', only a data set of columns with the same name is created. When I choose join = 'outer', all columns are added to the data set. But what I want to do is; Keeping the number of columns in the dataset the same and adding the column data with the same name in dataset2 to the columns with the same name in the dataset.I really researched it and made a long effort but I couldn't. I think I'm very confused. Thanks already for your help.

```
new = pd.concat([dataset,dataset2] ,join='inner')
```

dataset:

```
        Message Source     Customer Id        Social Medya          Subject
        0     Whatsapp           1047           İnstagram     Product information                         
        1     Whatsapp           6211           Facebook      Product İnformation
```

dataset2:

```
        Message Source     Customer Id     Social Medya      Contact Number
        0     Whatsapp           1256           İnstagram          005115..                          
        1     Whatsapp           5687           İnstagram           005115..
```

The table I want to create

```
        Message Source     Customer Id        Social Medya          Subject
        0     Whatsapp           1047           İnstagram     Product information                         
        1     Whatsapp           6211           Facebook      Product İnformation
        2     Whatsapp           1047           İnstagram                                  
        3     Whatsapp           6211           Facebook
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what I have tried based on your problem.

Firstly, we have 2 data like below:

list1.txt

```
Message Source,Customer Id,Social Medya,Subject
Whatsapp,1047,İnstagram,Product information                         
Whatsapp,6211,Facebook,Product İnformation
```

list2.txt

```
Message Source,Customer Id,Social Medya,Contact Number
Whatsapp,1256,İnstagram,005115
Whatsapp,5687,İnstagram,005115
```

Then, we create the script in terms of seeing the same columns, selecting the data, and concatenate with the "base" dataframe.

Here is the example:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.read_csv('list1.txt')
df2 = pd.read_csv('list2.txt')
headers = pd.concat([df1,df2] ,join='inner').columns
df3 = pd.concat([df1,df2[headers]], join='outer', ignore_index=True)
print(df3)
```

Finally, we can get what we want based on what you are expected on the question

```
  Message Source  Customer Id Social Medya                                       Subject
0       Whatsapp         1047    İnstagram  Product information                         
1       Whatsapp         6211     Facebook                           Product İnformation
2       Whatsapp         1256    İnstagram                                           NaN
3       Whatsapp         5687    İnstagram                                           NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

Atm it sees like you just want to duplicate dataset1, when looking at your Customer_ids
If you want normally all information you need a "full" join, which includes all data that matches or has no match.

But if you want something like this:

```
Message Source     Customer Id        Social Medya          Subject
        0     Whatsapp           1047           İnstagram     Product information                         
        1     Whatsapp           6211           Facebook      Product İnformation
        2     Whatsapp           1256           İnstagram                                  
        3     Whatsapp           5687           İnstagram
```

I would rather kill the col "Contact Number" and make something like this:

```
df1.append(df2)
```

Until you dont give us more information, which columns you really want and what information is really needed. I can only guess. As i said. atm it looks more like a duplicate. Maybe I'm missing something.